# USB Bootable Ubuntu

Tags: installation, boot, usb, live-usb, usb-drive

I am a newbie at this so please go easy.

I just bought a brand new Sandisk 32GB USB Cruzer Blade. It is genuinely 32GB. I then followed the instructions on ubuntu.com for making it a bootable USB.

All that worked perfectly, however on booting from the USB drive I noticed that there is only 1.1GB - not enough space for installing VM Player (and certainly not Linux Mint inside that).

Forgive my naivety, but I would have expected more memory available than that given its a 32GB drive.

What do I have to do increase the available space? Can I make use of all 32GB? Is there enough space for the drive to be bootable, have VM player, Mint Linux and other applications too?

I saw somewhere that the maximum is 4GB. Is that right? If so, then that is not much use.

Your help is much appreciated.

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

try [unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) for your favourite OS. instructions are also on the same page besides ubuntu needs atleast 2GB of PenDrive size.